# Spring MVC URL for the AbstractController

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller that inherits from the org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController class

I have configurated it in this way:

```
  <bean name="/gameServiceController.json" class="xx.xxx.GameController"/>
```

so can accepts url of this form

```
 http://<hostname>:<port>/<context-path>/gameServiceController.json
```

but the customer has provided to me the requirement to write URL in this way

```
 http://<hostname>:<port>/<context-path>/createNewGame?parameter=<value>
```

but I think that is not possible to map this type of URL with my controller. Anyone know the type of configuration that can be used in order to configure this type of URL mapping ?

Otherwise, is legal to ask to change the format of the URL in this way

```
     http://<hostname>:<port>/<context-path>/gameServiceController.json?command=createNewGame&phoneNumber=<phoneNumber>
```

so I can manage the command parameter in the "handleRequestInternal" method of my custom controller that inherits from the org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController class ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the legacy Controller framework, use [annotated controllers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller). There, you can easily use [URL templates](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates), something like this:

```
@Controller
public class GameController{

    @RequestMapping(value="/createNewGame?parameter={param}",
                    method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createNewGame(@PathVariable String param, Model model) {
      // do stuff here
      return "viewName"; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi,thank you for your reply but now I'm not able to configure my controller. My xml is this:<bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
 </bean>
 <bean name="/gameController.json" class="com.MyController">
 </bean>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/><bean id="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
</bean> but I have always 404 error while trying to invoke this resource : http://localhost:8080/fss/gameController.json/createNewGame?parameter=12

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting of the xml config. But do you know the correct configuration for this type of controller ?